# From Google Forms to Google Calendar - Date and TIme issues

Tags: forms, google-sheets

I am trying to modify a script I found online that seems to make the event an all day event, which I don't want, I want it to be just the time specified in the form/spreadsheet.

The spreadsheet is located here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApxazoOhNSK-dGFvZVhVOTQ1X3F3aWh4QTh3Wm9sbFE#gid=0

Here is the script I am using, but its not adding...

```
//this is the ID of the calendar to add the event to, this is found on the calendar settings page of the calendar in question
var calendarId = "<removed for privacy>";

//below are the column ids of that represents the values used in the spreadsheet (these are non zero indexed)
var startDtId = 4;
var endDtId = 4;
var titleId = 2;
var titleId2 = 3;
var descId = 7;
var tstart = 4;
var tstop = 5;
var formTimeStampId = 1;

function getLatestAndSubmitToCalendar() {
  var start = new Date(sheet.getRange(lr,tstart,1,1).getValue());
  var end = new Date(sheet.getRange(lr,tstop,1,1).getValue());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var lr = rows.getLastRow();
  var subOn = "Submitted on :"+sheet.getRange(lr,formTimeStampId,1,1).getValue()+" by "+sheet.getRange(lr,titleId,1,1).getValue();
  var desc = "Comments: "+sheet.getRange(lr,descId,1,1).getValue()+"\n"+subOn;
  var title = sheet.getRange(lr,titleId,1,1).getValue()+" "+sheet.getRange(lr,titleId2,1,1).getValue();
    createEvent(calendarId,title,start,end,desc);
}

  function createEvent(calendarId,title,start,end,desc) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var start = new Date(sheet.getRange(lr,tstart,1,1).getValue());
  var end = new Date(sheet.getRange(lr,tstop,1,1).getValue());
  var loc = 'Computer Center';

  var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
      description : desc,
      location : loc
  });
};
```

The original article is located here: http://bruceburge.com/2012/09/05/automatically-adding-events-to-a-google-calendar-from-a-google-form-submission/

I just can't seem to get the dates to work at all... If I use the original code it works fine, but the time is the full day, not the specified time...  I seem to have broken it in an attempt to make it work... Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I also tried this tutorial shich seems to be much much simpler, but kicks back the same error everyone else is in the comments of the video...

Answer (score 0):

It was a lot simpler than I though... I just removed some of his lines (the ones that set the hour and minutes to 0.  Once I removed that and changed a few things, I get the following which works just great:

```
//this is the ID of the calendar to add the event to, this is found on the calendar settings page of the calendar in question
var calendarId = "alcc.ccenter@gmail.com";

//below are the column ids of that represents the values used in the spreadsheet (these are non zero indexed)
var startDtId = 4;
var endDtId = 5;
var titleId = 2;
var titleId2 = 3;
var descId = 7;
var formTimeStampId = 1;

function getLatestAndSubmitToCalendar() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var lr = rows.getLastRow();
  var startDt = sheet.getRange(lr,startDtId,1,1).getValue();
  //set to first hour and minute of the day.
  var endDt = sheet.getRange(lr,endDtId,1,1).getValue();
  //set endDt to last hour and minute of the day
  var subOn = "Added :"+sheet.getRange(lr,formTimeStampId,1,1).getValue()+" by: "+sheet.getRange(lr,titleId,1,1).getValue();
  var desc = "Comments :"+sheet.getRange(lr,descId,1,1).getValue()+"\n"+subOn;
  var title = sheet.getRange(lr,titleId,1,1).getValue()+" - "+sheet.getRange(lr,titleId2,1,1).getValue();
    createEvent(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt,desc);
}​

  function createEvent(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt,desc) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var start = new Date(startDt);
  var end = new Date(endDt);
  var loc = 'Computer Centre';

  var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
      description : desc,
      location : loc
  });
};
```

My form has the following Columns - Timestamp, Name, Absence, Start, End, Reason, Comments.  They didn't need to be ne word but I changed them to one word headings because of the video example I was trying to follow... But the above code works miracles.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the way Forms handles dates to accommodate Calendar

```
function createEvent() {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
    var responses = form.getResponses();
    var len = responses.length;
    var last = len – 1;
    var items = responses[last].getItemResponses();
    var email = responses[last].getRespondentEmail();
    var name = items[0].getResponse();
    var bring = items[1].getResponse();
    var date = items[2].getResponse();
    Logger.log(date);
    var replace = date.replace(/-/g,”/”);
    Logger.log(replace);
    var start = new Date(replace);
    Logger.log(‘start ‘+start);

    //Logger.log(newStart.getHours());
    var endHours = 2+0+start.getHours();
    
    //Logger.log(start.getDay());
    var day = start.getDate();
    var minutes = start.getMinutes();
    var year = start.getFullYear();
    var month = start.getMonth();
    var hours = start.getHours();
    
    var d = new Date(year, month, day, endHours, minutes);
    Logger.log(d);

    var event = cal.createEvent(‘Class Party ‘+name+’ brings ‘+bring, start, d)
        .addGuest(email)
        .setDescription(name+’ you will be bringing ‘+bring+’ to the party.’);

    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, name + ’ a Google Calendar invite has been created for you’, name + ’ You filled out the Google Form for the date of ‘ + start + ’. Check your Google Calendar to confirm that you received the invite.\n’);
}
```